# Can't bring Linux TAP device up programically

Tags: c, linux, tun

I'm trying to implement a simple VPN as a learning experience, and I came across a problem. After I create a TAP device, I cannot bring it up. Here is a shorter version of my code:

```
typedef struct {
    int device;
    struct ifreq& ifr;
} AllocatedTap;

static AllocatedTap tap;
static struct ifreq ifr;
int fd, err;
char dev[16] = "\0"; // Let the kernel pick a name

if ((fd = open(TUN_CLONE_DEVICE, O_RDWR)) < 0) {
    return NULL;
}

memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));

ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TAP | IFF_NO_PI; 
if (*dev) {
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);
}

if ((err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr)) < 0) {
    close(fd);
    eturn NULL;
}

strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);

tap.device = fd;
tap.ifr = &ifr;

return &tap;
```

After that, I bring it up with:

```
int fd, err;

fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); // 0: automically chose protocol
if (fd < 0) {
    return -1;
}

tap->ifr->ifr_flags |= IFF_UP;

if ((err = ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &tap->ifr)) == -1) {
    return err;
}
```

This will always result in a `No Such Device` error when bringing the interface up. I can get it to work about half the time if I recreate the `ifr` struct while only carrying over the `ip_name` and `ip_addr` fields.

I expect for the code to bring the interface up to not err, and to actually bring said interface up.

I have tried, as stated above, recrating the `ifr` struct, which makes the code not error. However, using `ip a`, I've found out that the interface isn't up.

Can anyone help me figure out what going on?

Comment: I would try SIOCGIFFLAGS, then set IFF_UP, then call SIOCSIFFLAGS to be sure you are not overwriting  other flags.

Comment: I should add that instead of failing on `SIOCSIFFLAGS`, now that I am running `SIOCGIFFLAGS` beforehand just makes it fail on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i write same code as yours, and i met the same problem.
You shoule add ioctl(fd, TUNSETPERSIST, 0x1), then reopen the tun dev fd like this, and use TUNSETIFF again.

Comment: Did you... create an account to leave an answer on an almost two-year-old question? Thank you!!